# How to make purecomputed observables writable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Given this code:

```
self.loanResult = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var result = (self.loanAmount() / self.loanCount());
    return result;
});
```

As you can see `loadResult` is a [Pure computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html). It works fine, so that whenever `loanAmount` and `loanCount` change the result displays immediatly in `loanResult`.

```
<p>
    Loan amount <input data-bind="value: loanAmount, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
</p>
<p>
    Loan count <input data-bind="value: loanCount, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
</p>
<p>
    Loan result <input data-bind="value: loanResult, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
</p>
<p>
    <span id="alert" class="label label-info" data-bind="text: loanAlert"></span>
</p>
```

Now assume that user wants to change `loanResult`, I want to bind another property based on some conditions to `loanAlert`, So I created another Pure computed observable, But when I change the `loanResult` nothing happens:

```
self.loanAlert = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var result = self.loanResult() * self.loanCount();
    if (result >= data) {
        return "Yes";
    }
    return "No";
});
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `computed`s rather than `pureComputed`s?  I've not got round to trying `pureComputed`s yet, so unsure as to the exact effects they may have.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just wanted to use pureComputed because it's a recommended way.

Comment: Ok.  Where is `data` coming from?  A small repro may help here

Comment: assume that data is just a number.

Comment: Oh hang on, I just realised you've got a value binding to your `loanResult` computed.  Are you saying you want a user to be able to overtype the `loanResult` itself?  If so, you'll probably need to implement it as a [writable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @James, Actually I didn't know about [Writable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html). So As James mentioned I should use writable computed observables:

```
self.loanResult = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {
        var result = (self.loanAmount() / self.loanCount());
        return result;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        var result = value * self.loanCount();
        if (result > data) {
            self.loanAlert("OK");
        } else {
            self.loanAlert("No");
        }
    },
    owner: this
});
```